# How to transfer data from one table to another (DynamoDB on AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, transfer

How do I transfer data from one table to another in DynamoDB? I'm confused because tables and table-fields look absolutely identical.

Comment: Do you want to transfer data once or mirror an existing table constantly?

Comment: Use AWS Data Pipeline https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/

Comment: Dunedan, just one time

Answer (score 1):

To copy a source table to a new destination table, then on Demand Backup and restore should do the trick.  Details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorks.html

If you are looking to copy the data from a source DDB table to an EXISTING DDB table (and append the data to it), then consider Glue.

- DDB can be a source for Glue ETL: "connectionType": "dynamodb"
- DDB can be a destination for Glue ETL, but is a little more complicated.  You will need to use the [JDBC driver for DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/community/) and then set Glue to output to JDBC.  There are detailed instructions [here](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-jdbc-aws-glue.rst)

Comment: Restore writes data to a new table, but I need to transfer data from this table to the old

Comment: i just want transfer the items from the new table to the old

Comment: So the destination already has data in it, and you want to ADD data from the source table?

Comment: the destination hasn't data in it, this table is empty

Comment: see my edited response about Glue above... will that work?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this:

- Different Regions
- Python
- Pagination
- Error handling and logs

```py
import boto3


def migrate(source, target):
    dynamo_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
    dynamo_target_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

    dynamo_paginator = dynamo_client.get_paginator('scan')
    dynamo_response = dynamo_paginator.paginate(
        TableName=source,
        Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
        ReturnConsumedCapacity='NONE',
        ConsistentRead=True
    )
    for page in dynamo_response:
        for item in page['Items']:
            dynamo_target_client.put_item(
                TableName=target,
                Item=item
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    migrate('awesome-v1', 'awesome-v2')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to do it one time like you mention in the comments, I recommend doing a backup and restore. Restore always goes to a separate table, not the original one.